# QCoreApplication.processEvents behavior

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm doing work where timing is extremely important, and have a question about the behavior of processEvents(). When I call processEvents(), is it run on a seperate thread/process, such that it may still be running as more of my code is executed?

If not, is there any chance that my code continues executing after processEvents() but before all the pixels on my monitor are updated to the newest scene (perhaps because the operating system handles pixel drawing)? Pseudo code below

```
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.drawScene()
app.processEvents() #Force window to update to scene
print("Hi!") #Is there any chance of this being called before my screen's pixels are all set to the newest scene?
```

If the code after processEvents() does run before the screen's pixels are all updated, is there a way to guarantee that the screen is updated before continuing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QCoreApplication::processEvents()` runs in the same thread as you call it from, it does not use a seperate thread. It will process all events currently queued up in the event queue. If there is an event of type `QEvent::Paint` in the queue, it will trigger a repaint of the window. Your `drawScene()` will probably put a paint event into the event queue, by directly or indirectly calling `QWidget::update()`.

So yes, a call to `processEvents()` will finish a pending repaint and only return once the repaint event has been processed.

FWIW, `QProgressDialog::setValue()` internally calls `processEvents()` to make sure the progress bar is updated, so this has to work there as well.

The only reason I can think of that would cause the pixels not to be shown is the platform-specific code in the so-called platform plugin doing something asynchronous when repainting. One would need to double-check the platform plugin code of the OS you are using to be absolutely sure.

This actually seems to be the case on X11, which is async. Check the [docs for QTest::qWaitForWindowExposed](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtest.html#qWaitForWindowExposed) - internally it calls `processEvents()` in a loop, until `QWindow::isExposed()` returns true. So at least for initially showing windows, you need to run `processEvents()` in a loop to make sure the window is actually shown. I do not know if the same is needed for repainting.
See [the section "Visibility and Windowing System Exposure" in the docs of QWindow](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindow.html) for more details.

Comment: What do you mean by run `processEvents()` in a loop? It doesn't return anything as far as I can tell

Comment: I think the code explains it better than I could - look at the code of qWaitForWindowExposed at https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/testlib/qtestsystem.h.html#_ZN5QTestL21qWaitForWindowExposedEP7QWindowi